# LiveWire Offline State doesn't work when i change connectin State

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In [this link](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/offline-state) of `LiveWire` documentation I simply added this line in `header` of our web application

```
<div wire:offline>
    You are now offline.
</div>
```

when I refresh the page, it doesn't appear on `header` and when I disconnected internet connection same as `Airplane mode` in `Windows` I expect to see `You are now offline.`. but it doesn't any change, I check that by refreshing multiple page.

This part of `Livewire` how's it work? I have a same problem with `Polling` such as:

```
<div wire:poll>
    Current time: {{ now() }}
</div>
```

doesn't show the time every `2s` and have to refresh the page to see current time

Answer (score 2):

Livewire offline state only works within a Livewire component.

Create the component:

```sh
php artisan livewire:make Offline
```

Update the template `resources/views/livewire/offline.blade.php`:

```html
<div wire:offline>
  You are now offline.
</div>
```

Usage:

```html
<livewire:offline/>
```

You do not need polling to use this feature.

---

Toggle your online/offline state in Google Chrome developer tools likes this:
[image: Google Chrome Developer Tools › Network › Offline]